# How to calculate the sum faster

Tags: python, optimization, sum

**Memory limit: 256 MB**

**Time limit: 1 s**

Hello.

We have the following code:

```
N, M = list(map(int, input().split()))
stones = list(map(int, input().split()))

for __ in range(M):
    command, index, num = input().split()
    index, num = int(index), int(num)

    if command == "S":
        print(sum(stones[index:num + 1]))
    elif command == "M":
        stones[index] = num
```

Where:

1. N is the length of list `stones`
2. M is number of `commands`
3. 1 ≤ N, M ≤ 10**5
4. commands in form `{type} {index} {index2 or value}` of two types:

   - 'S' to print sum of items in range `[index; index2]`
   - 'M' to change value of item on `index` to new 0 ≤ `value` ≤ 10

This code exceeds the time limit. So, how to optimize it?

#### Sample Input:

```
9 10
1 1 2 3 5 0 4 9 4
S 2 4
S 8 8
S 0 8
S 4 5
M 5 9
S 0 8
S 4 5
M 0 7
S 1 8
S 0 5
```

#### Sample Output:

```
10
4
29
5
38
14
37
27
```

Comment: If you update the item of a list with `b`, and the previous value was `a`, the new sum is `s+b-a` (with `s` the old sum).

Comment: So you can define a "sumtree" that stores the sums over the ranges in a binary tree. Then every sum call is *O(log n)*, and updating is *O(log n)* as well.

Comment: `sum(stones[i] for i in [x]range(index:num + 1))` does not build an extra list for each slice. Also you could just collect the output and have one print (with `'\n'.join`) in the end.

Comment: @schwobaseggl The generator is far slower than creating a slice for `sum` to iterate over internally. You are optimizing for memory usage, not run time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I don`t fully understand how to implement this binary tree. Can you explain this point in more detail?

Comment: @sabal202 you sum your numbers in pairs 1st + 2nd, 3rd + 4th, etc. Those pairs you again sum in pairs and so on, so you end up with all the sums for aligned 1, 2, 4, 8 etc blocks. You can piece these together to obtain the sums of ranges in logarithmic time. And updating also involves only O(log n) pieces.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, thanks.